# Tensorflow, sess.run() does not always return outputs in same order

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have developped a Python webserver that loads two tensorflow models at startup, and then will use these models to generate predictions.

I am using the pretrained object detection models [from tensorflow](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md) : `mask_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_atrous_coco_2018_01_28` and `faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_atrous_lowproposals_coco_2018_01_28`.

Here is my code :

Main.py :

```
from Classifier import Classifier
from flask import Flask, Response
import json


classifier_mask = Classifier("path/to/mask_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_atrous_coco_2018_01_28/saved_model")
classifier_nomask = Classifier("path/to/faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_atrous_lowproposals_coco_2018_01_28/saved_model")

image = ...

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/mask',methods=['POST'])
def do_detections_mask():
    output = classifier_mask.detection(image)
    return Response(response=json.dumps(output), status=200, mimetype="application/json")

@app.route('/nomask',methods=['POST'])
def do_detections_nomask():
    output = classifier_nomask.detection(image)
    return Response(response=json.dumps(output), status=200, mimetype="application/json")

app = Flask(__name__)
```

Classifier.py :

```
import cv2
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

class Classifier():
        def __init__(self, model_folder):
            self.sess = tf.compat.v1.Session()
            model = tf.compat.v1.saved_model.load(
                self.sess,
                [tf.saved_model.SERVING],
                model_folder
            )
            model_signature = model.signature_def["serving_default"]
            self.input_tensor = model_signature.inputs['inputs'].name
            self.output_tensor = [v.name for k, v in model_signature.outputs.items() if v.name]

            # make a first prediction on some image to 'warm up' the classifier (aka, initializing cuda/memory resources)
            # If we don't do that, the first prediction will take a lot more time than others
            self.sess.run(self.output_tensor, feed_dict={self.input_tensor: [cv2.imread("path/to/some_image.jpg")]})

        def detection(self, image):
            outs = self.sess.run(self.output_tensor, feed_dict={self.input_tensor: [image]})    

            if (len(outs) == 4):        # result of an object detection without masks
                counts_objects = int(outs[2][0])
                scores = outs[0][0][:counts_objects]
                labels = outs[1][0].astype(int)[:counts_objects]
                boxes = outs[3][0][:counts_objects]
                masks = np.array([])
            else:                       # result of an object detection with masks
                counts_objects = int(outs[3][0])
                scores = outs[0][0][:counts_objects]
                labels= outs[1][0].astype(int)[:counts_objects]
                masks = outs[2][0][:counts_objects]
                boxes = outs[4][0][:counts_objects]

            output_dict = {}
            output_dict['scores'] = scores.tolist()
            output_dict['labels'] = labels
            output_dict['boxes'] = boxes.tolist()
            output_dict['masks'] = masks.tolist()

            return output_dict
```

When I run my code on my local computer (PyCharm, on Windows), it works well. I get the expected behavior.

The instruction `outs = self.sess.run(self.output_tensor, feed_dict={self.input_tensor: [image]})` returns an array with the output of the model for the given image, with the structure.

```
outs[0] : the scores
outs[1] : the labels
outs[2] : the count of objects
outs[3] : the bounding boxes
```

For the `faster_rcnn` model and

```
outs[0] : the scores
outs[1] : the labels
outs[2] : the mask of objects
outs[3] : the count of objects
outs[4] : the bounding boxes
```

for the `mask_rcnn` model :

But when I run it in a docker image (`python:3.6.10-slim-buster` with some dependencies added as python-pip, libglib1.0-0, ...), I get a really weird behavior. The `outs` array do not have the same order as it does when I run it on my computer. And even worse, the order seems to change randomly at each run  (which is not happening on my computer). And so obviously, when I retrieve these outputs to put them in a dictionary, I get either a runtime error or a wrong result (and sometime a good result if I am lucky)

Does anyone have an idea of what is happening here ? 
And what can I do to solve (or bypass) this problem ?

I had the problem with all tensorflow versions I tried (1.12, 1.15.2 and 2.1), all on CPU.

Here is the `requirements.txt` I use in both cases :

```
absl-py==0.9.0
astor==0.8.1
boto3==1.12.31
botocore==1.15.31
cachetools==4.0.0
certifi==2019.11.28
chardet==3.0.4
click==7.1.1
cycler==0.10.0
Cython==0.29.16
docutils==0.15.2
Flask==1.1.1
gast==0.2.2
google-auth==1.12.0
google-auth-oauthlib==0.4.1
google-pasta==0.2.0
grpcio==1.27.2
h5py==2.10.0
idna==2.9
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.1
jmespath==0.9.5
Keras-Applications==1.0.8
Keras-Preprocessing==1.1.0
kiwisolver==1.1.0
Markdown==3.2.1
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
matplotlib==3.2.1
numpy==1.18.2
oauthlib==3.1.0
object-detection-0.1==0.1
opencv-python==4.2.0.32
opt-einsum==3.2.0
Pillow==7.0.0
protobuf==3.11.3
pyasn1==0.4.8
pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
pyparsing==2.4.6
python-dateutil==2.8.1
requests==2.23.0
requests-oauthlib==1.3.0
rsa==4.0
s3transfer==0.3.3
scipy==1.4.1
six==1.14.0
tensorboard==2.1.1
tensorflow==2.1.0
tensorflow-estimator==2.1.0
termcolor==1.1.0
urllib3==1.25.8
Werkzeug==1.0.0
wrapt==1.12.1
```

Edits :

- I have the same behavior if I only initialize one classifier.

Comment: Version of python on Windows? I suspect that this behavior comes from the fact that dict are not ordered on python <= 3.6

Comment: I am using Python 3.6 in both cases

Comment: Python 3.6.8 on my computer, and Python 3.6.10 on the docker image to be exact. I'll try to use the same version for both (with a Python 3.7)

Comment: I had the same behavior using Python 3.7.7